# Spring boot actuator: Health endpoint not showing details when other actuator's endpoints are secured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

**Goal**: secure all actuator endpoints, apart from info and health, but for health show the details when user is authenticated.

My pom has only `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-boot-starter-web` (Spring boot version: 2.1.6.RELEASE) and the whole config is

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding("info", "health"))
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }
}
```

and `application.yml`

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "when-authorized"
```

This secures all end points and gives unauthenticated access to info and health. But when health is accessed with credentials it does not return the details. It looks like the `management.endpoint.health.show-details="when-authorized"` is ignored in this case.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: ```.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health","info")).permitAll()``` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work using

```java
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()
        .excluding("info", "health")).authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
  }
```

or

```java
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("info", "health"))
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
  }
```